# Show that a point x€ Cl(A) iff there exists a sequence {xn} of points on A such that xn tends to X as n tends to infinity.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose the sequence converges to X.Then |xn-x|k,now xn€A for all n€N.Therefore epsilon nbd of x contains  atleast one point of A other than X.So x is a limit point of A.x€A'.so x€ Cl(A).
Now let,x€Cl(A).Then x€A or x€A'.When x€A' then it is done that x is a limit of the sequence {xn}.But if we assume that x€A and X does not belong to A' then how to prove that the sequence {xn} converges to x?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 0):

For such case, we can just set $x_n=x$ that is contained in $A$. Actually, such point $x \in A \backslash A'$ is called an isolated point.